# How can I traverse a 2D array in having sparse keys to access inner arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got this 2D array $userDesignatedCategory.

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => CEO 
        [1] => Assistant Art Director 
        [2] => Assistant Choreographer 
        [3] => Assistant Creative Director 
        [4] => Assistant Director 
        [5] => Assistant Editor 
        [6] => Assistant Equipment Engineer 
        [7] => Assistant Hair Dresser 
        [8] => Assistant Lighting Director 
        [9] => Assistant Make Up Artist 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => Senior Developer 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [0] => CEO 
        [1] => Script Supervisor 
        [2] => Creative Director 
        [3] => Anchor 
        [4] => Executive Producer 
        [5] => Director 
        [6] => Actor 
    ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
        [0] => Director 
        [1] => Executive Producer 
        [2] => Journalist 
        [3] => Producer 
    ) 
    [10] => Array ( 
        [0] => Head of Division 
        [1] => Vice President 
    ) 
    [11] => Array ( 
        [0] => Anchor 
        [1] => Chairman 
        [2] => Co Founder 
        [3] => Creative Director 
        [4] => Director 
    ) 
    [13] => Array ( 
        [0] => Associate Producer 
    ) 
    [16] => Array ( 
        [0] => Accounts Manager 
    ) 
    [20] => Array ( 
        [0] => Adventure Cameraperson 
        [1] => Cameraperson 
        [2] => Director Of Photography 
        [3] => Underwater Cameraperson 
    ) 
    [21] => Array ( 
        [0] => Director 
        [1] => Screenplay Writer 
        [2] => Writer 
    ) 
    [28] => Array ( 
        [0] => Director 
    ) 
    [50] => Array ( 
        [0] => Cameraperson 
    ) 
    [73] => Array ( 
        [0] => Accounts Manager 
        [1] => Actor 
        [2] => Aerial Cameraperson 
        [3] => Anchor 
    ) 
    [78] => Array ( 
        [0] => Accounts Manager 
        [1] => Aerial Cameraperson 
        [2] => Animator 
    ) 
    [79] => Array ( 
        [0] => Actor 
        [1] => Anchor 
        [2] => Adventure Cameraperson 
        [3] => Aerial Cameraperson 
        [4] => Animation Director 
        [5] => Animator 
        [6] => Assistant Make Up Artist 
        [7] => Assistant Manager 
    ) 
    [82] => Array ( 
        [0] => Adventure Cameraperson 
        [1] => Cameraperson 
        [2] => Director Of Photography 
        [3] => Associate Producer 
    )
    [86] => Array ( 
        [0] => Director 
        [1] => Producer 
        [2] => Writer 
    ) 
    [87] => Array ( 
        [0] => Co Founder 
        [1] => Vice President 
    ) 
)
```

I have sparse keys so I cant use `for($i=0;i 'less than' count;$i++)`

I've used `foreach($userDesignatedCatogery as $key => $value)` but it didnt help either.

How can I traverse this array to access inner arrays?

Comment: What exactly is your expected result?

Answer (score 3):

The simple traverse of your array.

```
<?php

  foreach($userDesignatedCatogery as $index => $pull) {
    echo '#' . $index . '<br>';
    foreach($pull as $id => $position)
        echo $id . ' => ' . $position . '<br>';
  }
```

Comment: How can i access only the whole indivisual inner array? I have to find intersection of userDesginationCategory[0] with all inner arrays.

Comment: $key = key($userDesignatedCategory);
$main = $userDesignatedCategory[$key];
unset($userDesignatedCategory[$key]);

$result = [];

foreach ($userDesignatedCategory as $index => $values) {
    if($intersect = array_intersect($main, $values))
        $result[$index] = $intersect;
}

//$result - there are your intersections

Answer (score 0):

you have two ways:

**first one:**

```
$count = count($userDesignatedCategory);
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
    foreach ($userDesignatedCategory[$i] as $item) {
        //some codes here
    }
}
```

**second one:**

```
foreach ($userDesignatedCategory as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $subitem) {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Comment: how to access key of inner arrays in second method?

Comment: @KaranTikku your arrays has no key names, you can count indexes , like this : `foreach ($userDesignatedCategory as $item) { $count=0; foreach($item as $subitem) {$current_index = $count;$count++; }}`

Comment: I accessed inner elements keys using array_search().

Comment: @KaranTikku it's for search in array , to use this function you most have value to find key! my code show **where i'm now** by counting steps! at all im happy if your problem resolved.